# How do I make a Java JAR unkillable by Windows user accounts

Tags: java, windows, process

Basically, I am creating some software to limit access to a few applications for my friend. I've written the framework and it works perfectly fine, but the Java application needs to sit there minimized in the tray without being killed by the user.

3 Questions

1. What is the best way to start this JAR with Windows?
2. How to I keep the application minimized in the system tray? I am using a CardLayout.
3. How do I keep the JAR from being killed?

Comment: 1. What have you tried? 2. What have you tried? 3. You don't.

Comment: I have searched through these forums and I really don't understand any of the tutorials to start your application as a service. Is there some other way? Also, for Q3, would it be possible to have the application run with Administrator permissions so the user cannot kill it? Would this have been a better idea to do in C#?

Comment: Sure, you could run under an admin or system account.  But i'd bet your app is not special enough for an admin or knowledgeable power user to overlook the gaping security hole they'd be opening up by doing so.

Comment: Plus, then the admin or system account can kill it.

Comment: This software is to limit his child from a few specific games. All I want it to do is start up with my friends account (which is the admin) so when his child logs into his account, the app will just sit in the tray and listen for events. This won't be distributed obviously.